# How to extract cell values from RasterStack and apply them to a new raster

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, raster

I am trying to take all cell values >=1 from a RasterStack and apply them to a new, blank raster.
I am unsure whether to try this through a for loop or if there is a way to do this via simple raster calculations. So far, I have the following:

```
dir <- "C://Users//path"
files<- list.files(path = dir,
                   full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".tif$")
raster_stack <- stack(files)
s <- subset(raster_stack, 38:48)
```

From here, I am unsure how to proceed. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are there also negative values possible in the raster layer or are they all NA or >= 0? What do you want to have as an entry in the new raster for cells with entries >= 1?

Comment: The RasterStack has 10 raster layers, each representing a year, with cell values ranging from 0 - 3. The new raster is blank. I am hoping to take the values of the raster layers that are >=1 and populating them into a new raster. So, the new raster should be able to show where values >=1 have occurred from the last ten years.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `newRaster <- calc(s sum)` to get a raster were all entries >= 1 show that there was a value >= 1 in the last 10 years?

Comment: @JKupzig I tried that but the newRaster does not have cells populated. It has the same resolution, extent and dimensions but no cells were populated. When plotted, nothing was graphed. The min and max cell values for the newRaster are num Inf and num -Inf respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
x1 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, xmn=-10, xmx=10, ymn=-10, ymx=10)
x2 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, xmn=-10, xmx=10, ymn=-10, ymx=10)
x1[,c(1,5,9)] <- 1
x2[c(1,5,9),] <- 1
plot(x1)
```

[image]

```r
plot(x2)
```

[image]

```r
s <- stack(c(x1, x2))
t <- sum(s)
plot(t)
```

[image]

If you wish to add particular layers, then:

```
t <- s$layer.1 + s$layer.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

With these example data

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
s <- round(s/100)
```

(it is not clear what you want for the cells that are < 1, "blank" has no meaning, but you probably want `NA` or `0`)

You can do this to get a TRUE / FALSE  raster (where TRUE is equivalent to 1 and FALSE is equivalent to 0)

```
x <- s >= 1 
plot(x)
```

or this to get a value (1 in this case) / NA raster

```
y <- ifel(s >= 1, 1, NA)
```

You can also use `classify` for that (it is more efficient)

```
m <- matrix(c(-Inf, 1, NA, 
                1, Inf, 1), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
z <- classify(s, m, right=FALSE)
```